# angular 2 integrating google maps yields ''cannot find namespace 'google'" error

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular

I'm trying to add the `google maps service` in my `angular 2 app`, but I'm getting following error: `Cannot find namespace 'google'.`

As seen on similar questions, I defined `declar var google: any` outside the class and I'm loading the `google-maps api` like this:

```
imports: [
   AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
     apiKey: "AIzaSyBfPIuViPbFbOzByKGGNKSuvNrbocxNyqE",
     libraries: ["places"]
   }),
   ...
]
```

I also installed `typings install dt~google.maps --global`, but it's still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding

```
/// <reference path="./../../../typings/globals/google.maps/index.d.ts"/>
```

into the class in which I used `google.maps`, everything worked fine.